Are storage reads in the pre-dispatch cached?
Are storage reads in the pre-dispatch cached?
Example, I'm doing a storage read in the pre-dispatch. Now the same storage read happens when executing the given extrinsic. Do I benefit from caching here or is that only the case when executing the extrinsic?
